# Function doesn't work in another function with sleep

Tags: python

I have a function that scrapes websites and returns a statement that is depending if it found certain keywords. This function is called checksite. When I run the function on its own it works great but I can't get it to work inside another function together with time.sleep.

This works great

```
    checksite()
```

This does not work

```
   while True:
        checksite()
        time.sleep(10)
```

I want the checksite-function run every 10 second. All help is appreciated!

Comment: We don't have enough information to help. Please create a [mre] that demonstrates the problem. We need to see more code and we need to know what "doesn't work" means. What's the behavior? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Do you get an error? Is your `checksite()` function above your `while` statement?

Comment: That should work. Please explain the error!

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: When I run the function by itself it always returns something after 10-30s. But when I run it together with time.sleep, it doesn't return anything at all after more than a minute.

Comment: When you say "return" do you mean `print`? In that case you might have to flush the output buffers.

Comment: I actually did flush the output for all print in the checksite-function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work. To check what is wrong, you could use this:

```py
def checksite():
   #blahblah
while True:
    print('starting')
    checksite()
    print('site checked')
    time.sleep(10)
    print('sleep function complete')
```

Then maybe you will get an idea of what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks! This somehow solved it.

Comment: Solved it??? I didn't mean it to. It was to help you identify the error. But still. 

Comment: Yes I understood that. In some wierd way it solved it. I'm just happy that it works now!

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know what the **checktime()** execution does.

If you dont see anything happening after 10 seconds and the script still executing more than expected, my first suggestion would be to know how much time the execution takes.

You can run this and get the amount of time:

```
import time
import datetime

def checktime():
    #Doing some execution
    print('execution...')

#Use:
while True:
    started = datetime.datetime.now()

    checktime()
    time.sleep(10)

    executed = datetime.datetime.now()

    print('The script runtime is: {0}'.format(executed - started))
```